# Code complete short key in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2017

What is code complete short key in C#? I expect to get whole function `tst_ArrayList` name by pressing CTRL+Space after `tst_Ar` in code below , but can't get it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    tst_Ar
    Console.ReadLine();

}


public void tst_ArrayList()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Hello");

}
```

UPD

TAB and 2*TAB both not completes code in VS 2015 C# while in VS 2013 C++ single TAB works fine. How to enable it in VS2015 c#?

Comment: There is no code complete key in C#, it's a programming language. Do you mean Visual Studio?

Comment: did you try using tab?

Comment: What editor are you using ?

Comment: I love the random answer to an not complete question, that is either unclear or no repro. Can't wait to see the answer taking about editting IntelliSense settings.json

Comment: @xdtTransform You're right. But its like solving riddles. In this case you even have enough information to make the right answer :-). But only one of the answers so far answers the question.

Comment: TAB and 2*TAB both not compleates code in VS 2015 C# while in VS 2013 C++ single TAB works fine. How to enable it in VS2015 c#?

Comment: @uwe, The first version question would have been a no repro on most of the editor as many autocompletion show all method.
It would have been Expected behavior on the other editor has they don't have auto completion. Even if visual studio is ofte use for c#, it's one in a see of possibility. Ps: Intelli Sense can be configure to show all possible word pased on typed word in any linked an avaidable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you are trying to access non static method inside static main method, that's why you are not getting anything after ctrl + space

make your method static and it will appear in intellisense

Comment: a non-static method can be called inside a static method by creating its instance so no need to make it static.

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil, Still by default Intelissense Give only what is possible at the moment you type. MyClass.Meth.., instance.Meth.., or Meth.. Won't give the same result are they have differnet "context".

Comment: @xdtTransform Agreed but that's not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

We have two option for Code completion in **Visual Studio**:

- try hitting **tab**
- try hitting **tab tab** to auto-complete some stuff like while writing properties for example.

*ctrl + space is used for intellisense to give you a hint of what options do you have.*

If that's what you wanted.

Comment: TAB and 2*TAB  both not compleates code in VS 2015 C# while in  VS 2013 C++ single TAB works fine. How to enable it in VS2015 c#?

Comment: @vico I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Tab works fine for code completion and double tab helps me with all my properties creation.

Comment: @vico I didn't enable it I am using default settings for this, Let me have a look and get back to you on this.

Comment: I did mistake - I have tasted VS 2013 C++ and not VS 2013 C# TAB's not work in VS 2013 C# either

Comment: @vico Please try this: open your VS, type "Keyboard" on the top right Quick Launch Bar. click on the first option from the drop-down, click Reset in the popup and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

It is CTRL+Space, but if that doesn't work go to tools > import and export settings > reset all settings. then it should work fine. If it was intellisense you were looking for